# How to update object attributes values in knockout.js at once

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-3.0, knockout-mvc

How to update object attributes values in knockout.js at once

the way i do is one by one like the example here

```
self.person = {
  id: ko.observable(),
  name: ko.observable()
};

self.person.id("1");
self.name.id("AAAA");
```

what i want is something like this

```
self.person = {
  id: ko.observable(),
  name: ko.observable()
};

var temp = {
id: "1",
name : "AAAA"
}

self.person(temp)
```

is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged the [knockout-mapping-plugin](/questions/tagged/knockout-mapping-plugin), here's how to do it using `ko.mapping.fromJS`:

```js
const person = ko.mapping.fromJS({
  id: undefined,
  name: undefined
});

const temp = {
  id: "1",
  name : "AAAA"
}

// Both undefined:
console.log(
  person.name(),
  person.id()
)

ko.mapping.fromJS(temp, person);

// Now set to 1 and AAAA
console.log(
  person.name(),
  person.id()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>
```

For more information, check out [the documentation](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).

Comment: How to do it without ko.mapping.fromJS

Comment: `self.person` cannot be set to be a plain object to then later be called as a function. Would you be happy with just a function like `patch(self.person, { id: 1, name: "AAA" })`? If you don't want to use the mapping library and roll your own code, you might want to add some more requirements for it.